# Calling subclass method after calling superclass method

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, subclass, superclass

Ultimately, I would like to call a subclass method AFTER calling superclass method.  I have a code something like this:

```
public class SuperClass
{
    protected WrapperClass<T> GetWrapperClass<T>()
    {
        return new WrapperClass(someStuff).Wrap<T>();
    }

    public SuperClass CommonMethod1()
    {
        // Do something
        return this;
    }

    public SuperClass CommonMethod2()
    {
        // Do something else
        return this;
    }

    // Many CommonMethods
}

public class SubClass : SuperClass
{
    public WrapperClass<SomeClass> OptionalLastMethod1()
    {
        return base.GetWrapperClass<SomeClass>();
    }

    public WrapperClass<SomeOtherClass> OptionalLastMethod2()
    {
        return base.GetWrapperClass<SomeOtherClass>();
    }
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
new SubClass()
    .CommonMethod1()
    .CommonMethod2()      // Returns SuperClass
    .OptionalLastMethod1();  // I would like to do something like this.
```

I would like to avoid casting SuperClass into SubClass like this:

```
var subClass = ((SubClass)new SubClass().CommonMethod1().CommonMethod2()).LastMethodToCall();
```

The Important point here is ease of use, not ease of implementation.  Any input is appreciated.

Comment: For fluent code like this, (generic) extension methods are your friends, as they have no trouble transcending hierarchies, and also eliminate the need for class authors to be clairvoyant. It's no accident they were introduced together with LINQ.

Comment: `OptionalLastMethod1` method is not part of `SuperClass` that's why you can not call it directly from `SubClass` instance. Either you have this method in `SuperClass` too and it that's not possible then having this method as an extension method created for `SuperClass` is another option.

Comment: @john my real question is how do I call subclass method from superclass (without using abstraction).    Your link talks about how to create chaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing this.
- removed some irrelevant code.

```
public class SuperClass<S> where S : SuperClass<S>
{
    public S CommonMethod1()
    {
        // Do something
        return (S) this;
    }

    public S CommonMethod2()
    {
        // Do something else
        return (S) this;
    }

    // Many CommonMethods
}

public class SubClass : SuperClass<SubClass>
{
    public WrapperClass<SomeClass> OptionalLastMethod1()
    {
        return base.GetWrapperClass<SomeClass>();
    }

    public WrapperClass<SomeOtherClass> OptionalLastMethod2()
    {
        return base.GetWrapperClass<SomeOtherClass>();
    }
}
```